# Derivatives of two functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

I need the limits ( for $x \rightarrow \pm \infty $) and the first three derivatives of the following two functions:

1) $f(x)=\dfrac{e^{-x}}{8-5x}$

2) $f(x)=\dfrac{x-1}{\sqrt{x-2}}-2$

1) $f'(x)=\dfrac{(5x-3)e^{-x}}{(8-5x)^2}$

after that I get stuck. I am trying it by using the quotient rule, but I
  always get different results. 
the limit as x approaches $\infty$ is 0, but for x approaching -$\infty$ I get $\infty$*0, so i guess I need L'Hopital's rule ?

2) $f´(x)= \dfrac{x-3}{2(x-2)^{3/2}}$

Same problem here. I rewrote $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-2}}$ as $(x-2)^{-1/2}$ and the derived the function by using the product rule.
For the limits of this function I think I also need L'Hospital's rule?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can use L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: In the first case the derivatives contain $e^{-x}$ which forces them to tend to 0 as $x→+∞$ and in the second you have an $x^{-1/2}$ behaviour with the same result. If $x→-∞$ the exponential blows up and the denominator becomes negative so the result is $-∞$ in the first case. In the second case the denominators become imaginary and you have to fix which roots you want to consider but it seems that the answer still is 0.

Comment: Ok, thank you both for your answers!
I still need to find the second and third derivatives of the above functions. Are there any shortcuts or do I just have to continue using the product and quotient rule ?

Answer (score 0):

we get for the first one
$$f'(x)={\frac {{{\rm e}^{-x}} \left( -3+5\,x \right) }{ \left( -8+5\,x
 \right) ^{2}}}
$$
$$f''(x)=-{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-x}} \left( 25\,{x}^{2}-30\,x+34 \right) }{ \left( 
-8+5\,x \right) ^{3}}}
$$
$$f'''(x)={\frac {{{\rm e}^{-x}} \left( 125\,{x}^{3}-225\,{x}^{2}+510\,x-2
 \right) }{ \left( -8+5\,x \right) ^{4}}}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
After another try I could calculate the derivatives except f'''(x) from the first function. I think this is because it get's really messy.
Would you be so kind to show me how you calculated that ?

Comment: @Pilotf4 The OP simply copied the result of a CAS, hence do not expect any mathematical explanation. Yes I know...